# Unreasonable route conflict error in python's falcon

Tags: python, falconframework

Usually falcons have excellent vision. It's weird that falcon in python sees that these two routes as conflicting:

```
app.add_route('/verifications/{template}/{email}', code_generation_resource)
app.add_route('/verifications/{email}/code/{code}', code_verification_resource)
```

error message:

> ValueError: The URI template for this route conflicts with another route's template.

I can easily work around it, but I'm wondering why they are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using same base paths.
If you add variables in falcon PATH, it only checks for base.

Comment: In the second route there is `/code/` which is static part of the path and should make it distinct.
I have these routes not conflicting: 
`app.add_route('/students/{username}', student.Resource())`
AND 
`app.add_route('/students/{username}/cvs/{filename}', cv.Resource())`.
Why are the ones in the question conflicting?